# Why can't the SVN plugin in Visual Studio Code find my svn.path?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, svn

I definitely have a working copy of svn on my Mac (I regularly update SVN code from Sublime), but the SVN plugin on Visual Studio Code can't seem to find it.

It was suggested I could find the path by typing this into console `echo $PATH` but what I get back is this: `/opt/subversion/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Here's the notification in VS Code:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your error is coming from this SVN extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnstoncode.svn-scm

That extension has a default setting of

```
  // Path to the svn executable
  "svn.path": null,
```

You will have to ***manually*** and ***explicitly*** tell it the path to your svn installation.
It (and VS Code) will not automatically find it for you.

First, get the path to your svn installation:

```
$ which svn
/usr/local/bin/svn

$ svn --version
svn, version 1.14.1 (r1886195)
...
```

(*The paths of course may differ on your machine.*)

Then, add that path to your [user or workspace settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

[image: settings UI]

In settings.json:

```
"svn.path": "/usr/local/bin/svn"
```

(*Use the path on your machine*)

Finally, reload VS Code and check the **Output** > **SVN** tab for logs that say the extension has successfully found it:

[image: output tab with successful svn]

The extension has a lot of other settings: https://github.com/JohnstonCode/svn-scm#settings.
Check and manually configure them yourself, if necessary.

Comment: It's also entirely possible that the OP never actually installed the CLI version of SVN--by leaving the "command line client tools" option unchecked when installing TortoiseSVN, for example.